# Fluent Assertions message for mismatched item in a collection comparison

Tags: fluent-assertions

I am comparing two collections using fluent assertions and given that number of items match but the item property values don't match, i get messages saying Expected item[2].Required to be False, but found True. Now what i am looking to do is to rather than saying item[2].Required it should say name.Required, i.e. i want to some how use one of the properties to be used in message so that i can straight away know that which item is it talking about. at the moment i have to look for the item in the table at that index to see which item is not matching , which becomes bit inconvenient when there are so many of them.

For e.g. comparing collections with following class where expected collection has say 5 elements with "Name" property set to A,B,C,D and E. I want to make fluent assertions tell me that A.Required or B.Required or C.Required is expected to be something but its something else and A.Address is expected to be something but it is something else B.Address is... and so on, instead of saying item[0].Required is expected to be something but its something else item[1].Required is expected to be something but is something else and so on.

```
public class Element
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public Required {get;set;}
   public Address {get;set;}
}
```

I tried looking for some answers but don't know what exactly to search for.
Please let me know if i can make question bit more clear if it isn't

Thanks

Comment: I don't get it. Where does `name` come from? You're comparing collections, right?

Comment: Hopefully the edits added some clarity ? @DennisDoomen

Comment: How would any library be able to figure out that you want to use `Name` as a identity of the `Element` instance in a collection? It's just a property.

Comment: just like it is able to figure out what properties i want include or exclude from assertions @DennisDoomen

Comment: I think we're misunderstanding each other. Can you include an example on how you would use FA to compare collections of `Element`?

Answer (score 0):

You could enable tracing for more details with

```
actual.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected, options => options.WithTracing());
```

And then if you would override `ToString()` on your `Element` you get your desired details in the trace.